# How do I install packages for python ML on ubuntu?

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu, matplotlib, installation

I am having problems trying to install the following packages on Ubuntu:

- scipy
- numpy
- matplotlib
- pandas
- sklearn

When I execute the command: 
`sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose`

I get the following message: 
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libatlas-dev : Depends: libblas-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libatlas3-base : Depends: libgfortran3 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libblas-common but it is not going to be installed
 python-dev : Depends: libpython-dev (= 2.7.11-1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.11-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 python-scipy : Depends: python-decorator but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgfortran3 (>= 4.6) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: python-imaging but it is not going to be installed
 python-setuptools : Depends: python-pkg-resources (= 20.7.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
 rstudio : Depends: libjpeg62 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgstreamer0.10-0 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: r-base (>= 2.11.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).`


So the packages are failing to install, but I really need these packages to begin a new project, how can I successfully install these packages?

Comment: The best way to avoid Python installation problems is to download Anaconda.

Comment: Read the error message! It contains instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run 'sudo apt-get -f install' as it suggests.

It seems your apt repository is broken. That command will fix it. (-f is for fix-broken) See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-get.8.html

*(p.s.: I deleted my earlier answer and decided to start a clean one.)*

Answer (score 0):

U cannot install it using apt-get. u need to install pip first. After you install pip, just google about how to install different packages using pip

Comment: I've tried to install pip itself, but when I attempt to install it using:
`sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential` 
I still get a list of comments like so: `Depends: python2.7-dev (>= 2.7.11-1~) but it is not going to be installed` .

Comment: This is not true. You _can_ install these packages with `apt-get`, but the installation may be painful.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

to verify that that download was successful try the following command.

```
pip -V
```

you should get something like this:-

```
#pip -V
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

after this just run following commands:-

```
sudo pip install numpy scipy pandas sklearn matplotlib
```

this will do the trick.